# Using ng-packagr it doesnt recognise my tsconfig paths

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, tsconfig, ng-packagr

Using ng-packagr for my Angular 6 and AngularCLI app and it doesn't recognise my tsconfig paths with I do the build. A normal ng build --aot --prod works fine though.

**These are my paths:**

```
 "paths": {
    "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
    "@env/*": ["src/environments/*"]
 }
```

**My tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["src/environments/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Errors I get tend to be Cannot find module .... be cause it doesnt know what @app is for example.

The app also works fine when serving e.g. npm start.

Comment: FWIW, my "app" directory is within "src", so I specify `paths` as: `"@app/environments/*": ["environments/*"]`

Answer (score 3):

It is already a reported issue in ng-packagr repo, you can copy your tsconfig configuration to ng-packagr configuration file as ng-packagr is not reading from your tsconfig but it has its specific configuration while tgzing (building).

You can check the issue in their repo thread here:

https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr/issues/519